# How do I remove account(s) from the mist?

Tags: mist

Running 0.7.5 Version on Mac.

Don't see any possibility to remove accounts.
They are test ones, with zero balance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the keys (files) associated with those accounts from the `~/.ethereum/keystore/` directory - or `~/.ethereum/testnet/keystore/` directory - and restart Mist.

Be careful to remove the correct keys. I'd recommend backing everything up first just to be safe.

Note also that even though those accounts are "empty", they can still be used to control any contracts that they created, so bear that in mind.

**Edit:**

Each platform has its own `keystore` location. Equivalent instructions apply to each.

- Mac: `~/Library/Ethereum/keystore`
- Linux: `~/.ethereum/keystore`
- Windows: `%APPDATA%/Ethereum/keystore`

Comment: This not work. I delete account from directrory, restart Mist, and two account is here.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have all backups before proceeding.

**For Mac OS**

Rename folder in Application Support folder

`mv ~/Library/Application\ Support/Ethereum\ Wallet ~/Library/Application\ Support/Ethereum\ Wallet_backup`

Restart Ethereum wallet